# C# Generics - Classes implementing other generic classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have a

```
public class A<T> where T : IBase
{
    //Does something
}
```

I need a second class that behaves like a collection of class A

```
public class B<A<T>> : IEnumerable<A<T>> where T : IBase
{
}
```

The problem is that I do not want to create classes like

```
public class B<A<MyCustomObjectP>> : IEnumerable<A<MyCustomObjectP>>
{
}

public class C<A<MyCustomObjectQ>> : IEnumerable<A<MyCustomObjectQ>>
{
}
```

and so on.. I would like to let the CustomObject be a generic type parameter that implements IBase.

I found that even doing this is illegal:

```
public class B<T, U> : IEnumerable<T> where T : A<U> where U : IBase
{
}
```

How could I achieve this type of behaviour, if this is illegal? Is there a better design pattern of sorts that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IBase` constraint is defined on `A<T>`, so it must be defined again on all generic classes, that want to use `A<U>` (using `U` to distinguish from `T` in `A<T>` class definition, but it can be called anything). You should be able to do simply:

```
public class B<T> : IEnumerable<A<T>> where T : IBase { ... }
```

Comment: Heh. That was simple. I was overthinking it. Thanks! This seems to do the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you need **a second class** that behaves like **a collection of class `A`.**

Since you have other classes (like `B`) inheriting from `IBase` as well, which you want to add, you can make the collection a collection of `IBase`.

Hence the solution would look like this (note that I have used `List` but you can easily replace that by `IEnumerable` - but then you have to implement methods like `.Add` yourself):

```cs
void Main()
{
    var items = new CollectionOf<IBase>(); // create list of IBase elements
    items.Add(new A() { myProperty = "Hello" }); // create object of A and add it to list
    items.Add(new B() { myProperty = "World" }); // create object of B and add it to list
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.myProperty);
    }
}

// this is the collection class you asked for
public class CollectionOf<U>: List<U>
where U: IBase
{
    // collection class enumerating A
    // note you could have used IEnumerable instead of List
}

public class A: IBase
{
    // class A that implements IBase
    public string myProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B: IBase
{
    // class B that implements IBase too
    public string myProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IBase {
    // some inteface
    string myProperty { get; set; }
}
```